# Compression phenomenon in Axial flow compressor

Tags: fluid-mechanics, compressors, turbomachinery

It is quite difficult for me to visualize how axial flow compressors work, as in, how air gets compressed by just flowing through a series of aero-foil shaped stator and rotor blades. How and where does the pressure build up of air actually takes place?

Comment: By the action of the rotor - commonly calculated with velocity triangles and covered in many textbooks like Engineering Thermodynamics Work and heat Transfer.

Comment: Before you start on axial compressors, you need to get kinetic and potential energy clear, see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/56166/10902